# Rails routing/auth for singleton resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a resource `profile` which I want users to be able to access in various ways.  I want the logged in user to be able to access their own profile from these routes:

```
GET /profile
GET /profile/edit
PATCH /profile
PUT /profile
```

And I want profiles to be viewable from this route:

```
GET /profiles/:id
```

Profiles cannot be created or deleted and users cannot edit the profile of another user.  I also don't want a profile index exposed to the user, so none of these routes should be available:

```
GET /profile/new
POST /profile
DELETE /profile
GET /profiles
GET /profiles/:id/edit
PATCH /profiles/:id
PUT /profiles:id
DELETE /profiles/:id
GET /profiles/new
POST /profiles
```

I'm using this route mapping:

```
resources :profiles, only: [:show]
resource :profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

Two questions:

1. Am I going about this the right way?
2. When I submit the form at `/profile/edit`, it tries to PATCH to `/profiles/:id`, which is invalid.  It seems like it should PATCH to `/profile`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a gem like `cancan`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a singleton resource like `resource :profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update]` it assumes that there is just ONE of those for the whole application.

If you really think that users must have those routes, just map them to what they belong.

```
resources :profiles, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
get '/profile', to: 'profiles#show'
...
```

Comment: The documentation seems to disagree with you.  "Because you might want to use the same controller for a singular route (/account) and a plural route (/accounts/45), singular resources map to plural controllers. So that, for example, resource :photo and resources :photos creates both singular and plural routes that map to the same controller (PhotosController)."